# Excel - Vlookup with if,or,and

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

Given the data in b2:e22 [image: excel screenshot]

I am then using `=FILTER(B3:B22,C3:C22>=7)` to produce the three smaller columns below.

What i am then trying to do is create a forumla which will check each value in B2:B22 and see if it occurs in:
C27:C33 AND D27:D33 **or** C27:C33 AND E27:E34.

I've tried the below but it fails with a #value error.  Can anyone assist please?

```
=IF(OR(AND(VLOOKUP(B4,C27#,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B4,D27#,1,FALSE)),AND(VLOOKUP(B4,C27#,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B4,E27#,1,FALSE))),"Yup","Nope")
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the meaning of `C27#` in your formula? My Excel doesn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

### An IF OR/AND Combination

[image]

**In cell F3:**

- You don't need the 'small table'.

```
=LET(data,C3:E22,min,7,
    data1,INDEX(data,,1),data2,INDEX(data,,2),data3,INDEX(data,,3),
IF((data1>=min)*(data2>=min)+(data1>=min)*(data3>=min),"Yup","Nope"))
```

derived from the simple (copy down):

```
=IF(OR(AND(C3>=7,D3>=7),AND(C3>=7,E3>=7)),"Yup","Nope")
```

If you insist, you could do something like the following (adjust the `H3#`):

```
=LET(n,B3:B22,d,H3#,min,7,
    data1,INDEX(d,,1),data2,INDEX(d,,2),data3,INDEX(d,,3),
    BYROW(n,LAMBDA(r,
IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(r,data1)*XMATCH(r,data2))
    +ISNUMBER(XMATCH(r,data1)*XMATCH(r,data3)),"Yup","Nope"))))
```

**In cell H3 (spilling the small table)**

```
=LET(n,B3:B22,v,C3:E22,min,7,
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(v)),LAMBDA(rr,c,
IFERROR(HSTACK(rr,FILTER(n,INDEX(v,,c)>=min,"")),""))),,1))
```

- Note that you need to lock the `B` column to copy to the left i.e. to spill three columns:

```
=FILTER($B3:$B22,C3:C22>=7)
```